# Kalman Filter - Gaussian representation

Tags: noise, estimation, kalman-filters, statistics

I'm trying to understand well the kalman filter, as a result i'm having this question :
Why do we represent noise with a Gaussian ? what does this really mean intuitively ?

Comment: This may be more ontopic on [dsp.SE]. Do you want us to migrate your question there? Either way, I think you can improve your question by including some of your own thoughts, and which resources you have consulted. (This does sound like a rather basic question, so I assume it's covered in the pertinent textbooks.)

Comment: Yeah it is a basic question I think, I read the original paper of kalman 1960 where it's written that this is an assumption, but I can't figure out why I don't find it that intuitive. And yeah thanks for proposing to migrate the question i would like it if you do !

Comment: Well, if it's an assumption the chicken answer is: no idea; different assumptions lead to different models. So the question is really: Why is Gaussian noise a *useful* assumption? I think it's quite likely that the answer is something like "because we have measured under controlled conditions that such noise is, indeed, close to Gaussian". Boring answer, I guess? Anyway, migrating.

Comment: General remark: original research articles are usually a poor learning resource. In particular, assumptions common to the field won't be discussed. Textbooks on the matter (often written decades later) *will* discuss such things, so I recommend you check one out.

Comment: I might have some intuitions on Gaussian noise in general  to share, but I'd like to know that you want Gaussian noise definition in Kalman filtering context only?

Comment: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260996/gaussian-assumption-in-kalman-filter) answer helped me understand why. But more of a data based answer than intuition.

Comment: @MohamedBenmahdjoub, Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Gaussian assumption in the case of the Kalman Filter assists with solving the problem.

Since a Gaussian Random Vector stays Gaussian after any linear operator it means for the Kalman model if the initialization is Gaussian the whole process is Gaussian.

Since the Gaussian distribution is defined by the 1st and the 2nd moments it also means that if we solve the the Least Squares problem we get the optimal solution.